# Database read locking

Tags: spring, oracle, concurrency, transactions, locking

I have a use case where I need to do the following things in one transaction:

1. start the transaction
2. INSERT an item into a table
3. SELECT all the items in the table
4. dump the selected items into a file (this file is versioned and another program always uses the latest version)
5. If all the above things succeed, commit the transaction, if not, rollback.

If **two transactions begin almost simultaneously**, it is possible that before **the first transaction A** commits what it has inserted into the table (step 4), **the second transaction B** has already performed the SELECT operation(step 2) whose result doesn't contain yet the inserted item by the first transaction(as it is not yet committed by **A**, so not visible to **B**). In this case, when **A** finishes, it will have correctly dumped a file **File1** containing its inserted item. Later, **B** finishes, it will have dumped another file **File2** containing only its inserted item but not the one inserted by **A**. Since **File2** is more recent, we will use **File2**. The problem is that **File2** ***doesn't contain the item inserted by A even though this item is well in the DB***.

I would like to know if it is feasible to solve this problem by **locking the read(SELECT)** of the table when a transaction inserts something into the table until its commit or rollback and if yes, how this locking can be implemented in **Spring with Oracle as DB**.

Comment: "two transactions begins almost simultaneously" that sounds like multiple treads/processes try to access the databse simultaneously, is that correct?

Comment: @Alex, it could be different processes performing this transaction from different physical machines.

Comment: Are those transactions.. long or short?

Comment: it depends what you mean by long or short, normally several seconds.

Comment: I would encapsulate the DB opeartion in one process, that all other process has to access the DB through that proccess. Inside the proccess I would make a waiting queue that proccesses the DB-accesses in serial.

Comment: This highly depends on the DBMS you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you please provide some insight in the case of Oracle DB? Thanks?

Comment: So "dumping the file" is part of the db transaction?  Wouldn't there be a commit after inserting?  Seems strange that you only want other sessions to see the data if the first session can successfully dump the data to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of synchronization between the transactions:

1. start the transaction
2. **Obtain a lock to prevent the transaction in another session to proceed or wait until the transaction in the other session finishes**
3. INSERT an item into a table
4. SELECT ......
5. ......
6. Commit and **release the lock**

---

The easiest way is to use [LOCK TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm) command, at least in SHARE mode (SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE or EXCLUSIVE modes can also be used, but they are too restrictve for this case). 
The advantage of this approach is that the lock is automatically released at commit or rollback. 
The disadvantage is a fact, that this lock can interfere with other transactions in the system that update this table at the same time, and could reduce an overall performance.

---

Another approach is to use [DBMS_LOCK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#ARPLS021) package. 
This lock doesn't affect other transactions that don't explicitely use that lock. 
The drawaback is that this package is difficult to use, the lock is not released on commit nor rollback, you must explicitelly release the lock at the end of the transaction, and thus all exceptions must be carefully handled, othervise a deadlock easily  could occur.

---

One more solution is to create a "dummy" table with a single row in it, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_special_lock_table(
   int x
);
INSERT INTO my_special_lock_table VALUES(1);
COMMIT:
```

and then use `SELECT x FROM my_special_lock_table FOR UPDATE`
 or - even easier - simple `UPDATE my_special_lock_table SET x=x` in your transaction.
This will place an exclusive lock on a row in this table and synchronize only this one transaction.
A drawback is that another "dummy" table must be created.
But this solution doesn't affect the other transactions in the system, the lock is automatically released upon commit or rollback, and it is portable - it should work in all other databases, not only in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Use spring's `REPEATABLE_READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation levels:

> REPEATABLE_READ A constant indicating that dirty reads and
>   non-repeatable reads are prevented; phantom reads can occur. This
>   level prohibits a transaction from reading a row with uncommitted
>   changes in it, and it also prohibits the situation where one
>   transaction reads a row, a second transaction alters the row, and the
>   first transaction rereads the row, getting different values the second
>   time (a "non-repeatable read").
>
> SERIALIZABLE A constant indicating that dirty reads, non-repeatable
>   reads and phantom reads are prevented. This level includes the
>   prohibitions in ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ and further prohibits the
>   situation where one transaction reads all rows that satisfy a WHERE
>   condition, a second transaction inserts a row that satisfies that
>   WHERE condition, and the first transaction rereads for the same
>   condition, retrieving the additional "phantom" row in the second read.

with `serializable` or `repeatable read`, the group will be protected from non-repeatable reads:

```
connection 1:                          connection 2:

set transaction isolation level
    repeatable read
begin transaction
select name from users where id = 1
                                       update user set name = 'Bill' where id = 1
select name from users where id = 1              |
commit transaction                               |
                                                 |--> executed here
```

In this scenario, the `update` will block until the first transaction is complete.

Higher isolation levels are rarely used because they lower the number of people that can work in the database at the same time.  At the highest level, `serializable`, a reporting query halts any update activity.

Comment: @Zamani I think your example doesn't cover my use case. My use case involves insertions instead of updates and I am doing a range select (SELECT all rows) instead of selecting a single row. So REPEATABLE_READ would not work (cannot avoid Phantom Reads).

Comment: @Gab是好人, those are examples which I copied from web. insertion instead of update is also a `modification` and Oracle should understand this. selecting a range is same and your DB will understand these I think.

Comment: It is not the same, see http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-isolation-tutorial

Comment: @Gab是好人, that article says `SERIALIZABLE isolation level leads to a scenario where none of the issues mentioned above may occur` which is what you need I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to serialize the whole transaction. While a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE could work, it does not really buy you anything, since you would be selecting all rows. You may as well just take and release a lock, using DBMS_LOCK()